# Reflection incorrectly matching by-name parameters

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to detect by-name parameters in a method definition. My approach is based on [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757584/handling-by-name-parameters-in-scala-macro) `ByNameParam` solution.

Unfortunately, by-name parameters match to `TypeRef`s for repeated arguments, and vice-versa. See the below code for an example.

I assume that this is not the intended behavior. Is the bug on my end or is there a problem with the `Definitions` module?

```scala
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class X { def x(i: => Int, other: Int*) = i * 2 }

val typeSignature = typeOf[X].member(TermName("x")).typeSignature
val paramTypes = typeSignature match {
  case MethodType(params, _) => params map { _.typeSignature }
}
val repeatedParamDefinition = definitions.RepeatedParamClass
val byNameDefinition = definitions.ByNameParamClass

// prints "Got repeatedParamDefinition" twice
paramTypes map { signature =>
  signature match {
    case TypeRef(_, repeatedParamDefinition, args) =>
      println("Got repeatedParamDefinition")
      args
    case TypeRef(_, byNameDefinition, args) => 
      println("Got byNameDefinition")
      args
  }
}

// Prints "Got byNameDefinition" twice
paramTypes map { signature =>
  signature match {
    case TypeRef(_, byNameDefinition, args) => 
      println("Got byNameDefinition")
      args
    case TypeRef(_, repeatedParamDefinition, args) =>
      println("Got repeatedParamDefinition")
      args
  }
}
```

Scala Version: 2.11.4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_65)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a pattern like `TypeRef(_, byNameDefinition, args)`, `byNameDefinition` is a fresh variable, not a comparison with your existing `val byNameDefinition`. Because that variable isn't used, it's effectively the same as `TypeRef(_, _, args)`. To avoid this, you need to surround it with backticks or to name it starting with a capital letter.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks!